# App breaks links with whitelist after being running in background

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, meteor-blaze

I hope someone can help me. I have an app running for both ios and andorid systems. Everything works well with ios but for some reason it breaks connection with some android devices (not all) for example: Xiaomi Mi A2, BQ Aquaris M10...

My app is using Cordova and the connections are set in whitelist. It specially happens with youtube videos, they run normally till the app stays in background for some minutes, and then below image happens:

[image]

Does any one know why it happens?

Comment: Background sounds like a ddp reconnect issue. Can you log your Meteor.status() for those devices  before going Background then in Intervalls during Background and when coming Back from Background?

Comment: Yes! its connected and working well, connection with server is not lost. It seems it only breaks connection with external channels defined in whitelist such as youtube. Weird that it only happens with Android

Comment: Okay can you please add your **anonymized** mobile config, settings, package.json and .meteor/packages?